# How to generate a random IIS port for a dotnet new custom project template?

Tags: .net, templates

When you create a new Web project, it creates a `Properties\launchSettings.json` file with configuration for IIS like this:

```json
    // ...
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:34390",
      "sslPort": 44333
    }
```

The port numbers are randomized. This is their [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/662795d5aa2d4608e33a972415c81699e8af5736/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.ProjectTemplates/content/RazorPagesWeb-CSharp/Properties/launchSettings.json) and there doesn't seem to be anything special:

```json
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
      //#if (HasHttpsProfile)
      "sslPort": 44300
      //#else
      "sslPort": 0
      //#endif
    }
```

I am making a custom web template but I am stumbling at this. How do I generate a random port number like them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the source code for it, turned out I was looking at the wrong place. The static number there is replaced by a declaration in the [template.json](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/662795d5aa2d4608e33a972415c81699e8af5736/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.ProjectTemplates/content/RazorPagesWeb-CSharp/.template.config/template.json#L307C20-L307C20), not in that file or the `.csproj` file:

```
        "iisHttpsPortGenerated": {
            "type": "generated",
            "generator": "port",
            "parameters": {
                "low": 44300,
                "high": 44399
            }
        },
        "iisHttpsPortReplacer": {
            "type": "generated",
            "generator": "coalesce",
            "parameters": {
                "sourceVariableName": "iisHttpsPort",
                "fallbackVariableName": "iisHttpsPortGenerated"
            },
            "replaces": "44300"
        }
```

It uses [.NET templating `random` symbol](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-Symbols-Generators#random) in case it's helpful for anyone.